# ember js count number of records in store

Tags: ember.js

When I try:

```
return this.store.findAll('book');
```

The console returns a list of books like:

```
books/1, books/2, books/3
```

If I install the ember add-on then in DATA I will have 'book(3)'.

Now How can I show this number to the templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your route is looking like this:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.store.findAll('book');
  }
});
```

you should be able to write the following in your route's template:

```
<p>Our library has {{model.length}} books!</p>
```

This should output `Our library has 3 books!` or similar.